# Did you call for a Date?

Tags: visual, rebus, knowledge

This image represents a specific date:

[image: Picture]

Disregard the poor quality of the image, consider all the little squares to be the same. :)

> What specific date am I looking for? (Year, Month, Date)

Comment: Is it intentional that that one box on the bottom right isn't lined up properly?

Comment: This is specifically addressed in the question: "Disregard the poor quality of the image, consider all the little squares to be the same. :) "

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be:

> 2004, May 18th

In which...

> Randy Johnson threw a perfect game in his last year as a Diamondback against the Atlanta Braves. The first for the Diamondbacks, too. This is known as 27 up, 27 down.

Answer (score 9):

Is it

> July 12, 1979

Because that date was

> [Disco Demolition Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disco_Demolition_Night), a promotion by Bill Veeck (as in Wreck), intended as a double header, but the second game was canceled due to the fracas and damage done during the first game.
>
>  The picture above shows an un-filled-out baseball scorecard, indicating (possibly) a game that was never played.

Comment: Good guess, but no.

Answer (score 5):

> May 12, 1917

because

> both pitchers had a no-hitter through 9 innings?
>  http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/CHN/CHN191705020.shtml

Answer (score 4):

> March 31, 1998
>  The date of first Arizona Diamondbacks home game

Because:

> The logo in the back of the image is the second Diamondbacks logo (which might be the date you're looking for too) and the squares are lined up like the pattern on a diamondback snake.
>
>  Really I can throw darts at a bunch of D-Backs dates, but I don't have any clue as to which one you're looking for :)

Comment: Getting Closer!

Comment: I'm not sure why you commented on my answer when the accepted answer was posted two days ago?  Good puzzle btw :)

Comment: My previous (deleted) comment was something of a spoiler, so I changed it to something more innocuous.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> June 19, 1907

Reasoning:

> Placing the number 2727 (the count of squares twice, once for each row) in a Microsoft Excel cell and setting it to a date gives this date.
>  **EDIT:** Also the format for the Excel date formula is Date(Year,Month,Day)

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer

> 27/9/1980 (or 9/27/1980 for those in the US)
>  Because there are 27 squares in a block, 9 in a row. That small image in
>  each box looks like pac-man and the release year for that was 1980.